# web service that can take a code snppet and test it

Tags: language-agnostic

I am looking to build an educational web service where the end user can type up the code in some language (say Java or python) for a given problem and the service should be able to tell if the code compiles and show output of the code for a few test cases. I am trying to get an idea from the community about a) if something like this exists b) how to build it.

Obviously this service will support a very limited subset of the language for security reasons. It would be cool to be able to do majority of this on the client side, but I'd be happy with doing this on the server side as well.

Are there any such frameworks that I can use for creating a sandbox environment?
Is there any particular language for which it would be particularly easier?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [iDeone API](http://ideone.com/api).

> **What is ideone?**
>
> Ideone is something
>   more than a pastebin; it's an online
>   compiler and debugging tool which
>   allows to compile and run code online
>   in more than 40 programming languages.

Comment: thanks, this is great (voted up). Although what I am looking to do is be able to do on my own server. If there is a framework or api that I could use to create sandbox environment to run gcc or something like that within a webserver, that would be great.